# Proving the functions will intersect, so there is an $A \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(A) = g(A)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, proof-writing

I am struggling to formalise proof for the following statement:

So given continuous functions $f,g$ defined with constrains $g(x) \to +\infty $ as $x\to -\infty$ and $g(x) \to -\infty $ as $x \to +\infty$ and $f(x) \to +{\infty} $ as $x\to +{\infty}$ and $f(x) \to -{\infty} $ as $x\to -{\infty}$.

Then proof is about the functions will intersect, so there is an A in real numbers where $f(A) = g(A)$.

I was thinking to use the Intermediate Value Theorem, so firstly defining $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$. Then $h$ has points $[a,b]$ with $ h(a) ≥ 0 ≥ h(b)$. Then setting $a_0 \leq a_1 \leq b_1 \leq b_0$ and $b_1 - a_1 = (b_0 -a_0)/2$ then we can get sequences a and b such that $a_0 \leq a_{n-1} \le a_n \le b_n \le b_{n-1} \le b_n$ Because f and g are continuous, h is also continious. Then since g(x) goes to infinity and f(x) goes to minus infinity as x goes to infity, we can say that $h(a) \geq 0 \geq f(b),$ then there must be common point c that $h(c) = 0,$ meaning $f(c) = g(c)$ so the functions will cross.

Not sure if that is rigorous enough, this is my first analysis course ever so struggling with the proofs. Any help with this is welcomed.

Comment: A condensed version: $h$ is clearly continuous and satisfies $h(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ and $h(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$. By the IVT, there must exist an $A \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(A) = 0$.

Comment: @amWhy yes, sorry

Comment: No need to apologize, beginner :-)  I've edited your post to include that.